# How to replace ' ' value instead of null when retrieved from hibernate createCriteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want replace '' value instead of null value in database when i retrieved from hibernate createCriteria using entity annotations.

```
List<Configuration> kist=new ArrayList<Configuration>();        
Criteria crq=getSession().createCriteria(Configuration.class);
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `Interceptor` class. According to me, it is one of several ways to achieve your requirement.

See this link, it is well explained: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/